# What is the easiest way to mix document classes in the same PDF?

Tags: document-classes

I would like a letter at the start of my report, but it would be a different document class.

Could I use the same .tex file, with `\begin{document}\end{document}\begin{document}\end{document}`?

Comment: `TeX` will stop the compilation process the first time it sees `\end{document}` (non verbatim). So, no you cannot use `\begin{document}\end{document}\begin{document}\end{document}`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would write the letter as a different document, compile it into a PDF and include it in the report using `\includepdf{<filename>}` from the `pdfpages` package. This avoids the double documentclass, but only works with full pages. However, this seem what you want anyway.

Answer (score 13):

Just for fun, you can have it all in "one file" (note that `shell-escape` must be active).

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{filecontents,pdfpages}

\begin{filecontents*}{myletter.tex}
\documentclass{letter}
\begin{document}
This is my letter.
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\immediate\write18{pdflatex myletter}

\begin{document}

\IfFileExists{myletter.pdf}{\includepdf{myletter.pdf}}{}

My report.

\end{document}
```

Comment: In this case you might want to load the `filecontents` package as well (before the environment of course) to ensure that the external file is outdated when you change the content changes. Otherwise an existing file will never be overwritten.

Comment: Okay, will do. I'm using shareLaTeX for the collaboration on the report, which doesn't allow compilation options, so not sure if this approach will work... but I will try!

Comment: @MartinScharrer Thanks Martin. This 'feature' of the `filecontents` environment has bothered me for a while. Updated answer.

Comment: @cjorssen -- This is a very neat solution.

Comment: Wouldn't this rather be the job of a `Makefile`?

Comment: I'm using Windows and TeXstudio and therefore a `makefile` isn't really the way to got -- is there a way to pass commands from the first document to the second such as `\newcommand{\EMAIL}{cccc@sss.com}` ?

Answer (score 3):

There are command-line tools that can combine several PDF files into one, such as `pdftk`:

```
pdftk a.pdf b.pdf output a_plus_b.pdf
```

Combine this with a `Makefile` or a similar mechanism to compile only what's necessary. `latexmk` can do a nice job here, too:

```
latexmk -pdf a
latexmk -pdf b
```

will run pdflatex, bibtex etc. on both `a.tex` and `b.tex` *as often as necessary*.