# Passing details (commands) between two

Tags: miktex, document-classes, shell-escape, scripts

I'm working on my CV and the covering letter and I would like to compile both documents (two different document classes) in one run (more or less). Either way, I followed the example as shown in this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47430/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-mix-document-classes-in-the-same-pdf/47433#comment630247_47433) (requires shell-escape) but unfortunately because I still have "virtually" two different document I can't pass commands and definitions (a la `\newcommand{\EMAIL}{cccc@sss.com}`) (just to make sure to use the same addresses etc. in the whole document). I thought about using a script file but because I'm using Windows (with `MiKTeX` and TexStudio) I rejected the idea. Is there a way to pass this information between two different document classes?

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcommand{\EMAIL}{cccc@sss.com}


\usepackage{filecontents,pdfpages}

\begin{filecontents*}{myletter.tex}
\documentclass{letter}
\begin{document}

My E-Mail: %\EMAIL ->Problem!!!

\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\immediate\write18{pdflatex myletter}

\begin{document}

\IfFileExists{myletter.pdf}{\includepdf{myletter.pdf}}{}

My E-Mail: \EMAIL

\end{document}
```

Comment: why the complication of shell escape etc/ why not just put `\newcommand{\EMAIL}{cccc@sss.com}` into `mysettings.sty` and then just use `\usepackage{mysettings}` in both documents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would avoid the complication of shell escape etc, and just put

```
\newcommand{\EMAIL}{cccc@sss.com}
```

into `mysettings.sty` and then just use

```
\usepackage{mysettings}
```

in both documents.