# How to import a tex document as appendix?

Tags: input

I have two tex file "one is "cornell" template another one is "article" template that one is created from jupiter notebook. If I input this article front is missing but it run successfully as an individual. I cut user package and paste as main document header but it can not help. If there any other way.

Comment: can you not just make a copy of the body of you `article` document (the part between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` but not including those commands and then simply `\input` that at the end of your main document.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is the easiest way to mix document classes in the same PDF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47430/5764)

Comment: format is change to do that