# How do I display list of symbols without using documentclass?

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl

I am using a template provided by the school to write my thesis. On the `main.tex` I am using `\documentclass[11pt]{thesis}`. Now I am trying to add a list of symbols page, I am using this code

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
Here is an example:
\nomenclature{\(c\)}{Speed of light in a vacuum}
\nomenclature{\(h\)}{Planck constant}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

Doing this does not display other pages.
Removing the `\documentclass{article}`  throws an error `Can only be used in preamble`.

How can I display the symbol page?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. What happens when you use the code inside your own document class? Do you get errors? Can you edit your question to give a link to the document class you are using?

Comment: [What is the easiest way to mix document classes in the same PDF? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47430/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-mix-document-classes-in-the-same-pdf) ■ [Change document class per page - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89792/change-document-class-per-page) ■ [document classes - In a LaTeX project (how) can I use more than one documentclass? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530226/in-a-latex-project-how-can-i-use-more-than-one-documentclass)

Comment: Although it might as well be easier to simply use nomencl package with your thesis documentclass.

Comment: @user202729 The question really seems to be about using the `nomencl` package not mixing document classes which is something to be avoided in almost all cases.

Comment: @AlanMunn That could solve the problem, not necessarily the best way. Although includepdf is not that bad if the OP allows it; and if there's some conflict then it's worse

Comment: You could create an invisible page using \include and \includeonly, but you would have to reset the page counter.

Answer (score 2):

The MWE that you show is correct. Have you run `makeindex`? When you compile your file with a nomenclature, let's say  named `whatever.tex`,  let's say  with `pdflatex`, a new file `whatever.nlo` is created in your working directory.

Then, you should invoke `makeindex`:

```
makeindex whatever.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o whatever.nls
```

And then, you should compile again, so that `pdflatex` can load `whatever.nls` to include the nomenclature list. In summary:

```
pdflatex whatever.tex
makeindex whatever.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o whatever.nls
pdflatex whatever.tex
```

The output of your code correctly processed:

---

[image: mwe]

---

Most probably you can include the code for the nomemclature directly in `main.tex` instead than using separate document, but taka into account that here you could need one or more  additional compilations with  `pdflatex`, as well as run before another programs, as `biber` or `bibtex`, to resolve cross-references, make the references, etc.

Comment: Not the issue here though. The issue is buried in the question text (custom thesis class), not the MWE.

Comment: It is not clear if he wanted to do the nomenclature in `main.tex` or in a separate document, but anyway, as  he cannot compile  the MWE code, inside a `thesis` class the issue most  probably is the same, although of  course, with these clues and an unknown custom class is impossible to be sure.

Comment: @Fran the symbols page is in separate file which i would include in the `main.tex`

Comment: @Starrrrck Then  is simply that, and include the PDF as  image or using pdfpages. But this could have  disadvantages compared with just load `nomencl`  in the preamble of the main file and the rest in the body of the same file, or in a child file as `mylist.tex` and  include it using  \input{mylist}`.